# Android development requires JDK 8(1.8)64-bit

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, unity2.0

I use unity 2020.3.13, i start to work with android game. I try to set the JDK with JDK that I got from Android Studio, but i get this error:

```
Incompatible Java version '16'
Android development requires JDK 8(1.8)64-bit. Having Java Runtime Environment(JRE) installed is not sufficient.
```

I'm confused because my JDK version is more than 8 but still can't. Do I have to install the exact JDK version 8? And is it better to use Unity's provided JDK, SDK, NDK, and Gradle or the ones from Android Studio?

Comment: You need exactly 8.

Comment: Is it better if i use Unity's provided JDK, SDK, NDK, and Gradle or i need to download them manually?

Comment: If you build with Unity, they give you the supported and compatible packages, so unless you need some particular feature, i think the best option is to follow Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it turned out that the problem was with my JDK installation. i re-installed the android module in unity and used the jdk given by unity and everything worked fine